# What's the best way to use CSS3 Transitions & Animations with jQuery addClass/removeClass?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, css-transitions, css-animations

There are a lot of questions on SO about how to solve specific problems related to jQuery `addClass()` + `removeClass()` and CSS3 animations/transitions.

Generally, I'm concerned about the best way to do the following:

1. graceful degradation for older browsers (that don't fire e.g. `animationend` events)
2. detect whether a transition is already running
3. stop or restart running transitions
4. change parameters mid-transition

Specifically, I have some animation classes I'm working with, which can be inspected in the [requisite jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/alexweber/v6jcq6w8/).

In the fiddle, I've defined classes that provide "appear" and "disappear" animations, using `opacity` and `max-height`. You can see both of those running when the fiddle starts up.

Then, I want to make elements appear/disappear when certain events are fired. I'm trying to use `addClass()` & `removeClass()` (and even jQuery UI's [`switchClass()`](http://jqueryui.com/switchClass/)) at the suggestion of another post here on SO. As you can see in the fiddle (by clicking "click to animate" and "click to reset"), these don't behave as one might expect.

What's the best way to handle this tricky problem?

P.S. I'm aware of the [Web Animations API](http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-animation), but it's just a draft right now. jQuery and jQuery UI have `animate()`, but I'd rather use standard CSS if possible.

Comment: Have you heard of [GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap)? **1.** [Backward compatible animations](http://greensock.com/why-gsap/). **2.** [.isTweening()](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/isTweening/) or [.isActive()](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/isActive/). **3.** [.pause()](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/pause/) or [.restart()](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/restart/). **4.** [.updateTo()](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/updateTo/).

Comment: Green Sock is rock! Coming from the ActionScript world, it solve a lot of animation problem. I am using GSAP with AngularJS and solve a lot of problems you mentioned here.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting GSAP. I have indeed heard of it. This doesn't answer my question about this specific case, nor does it leverage CSS3 animations/transitions. That said, I will consider using GSAP in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to

```
$("#toggle").click(function(){
    var $one = $('#one');
    var $two = $('#two');
    var $three = $('#three');

    $one.removeClass('appear-lg');
    $one[0].offsetWidth = $one[0].offsetWidth;
    $one.addClass("disappear-lg");

    $two.removeClass('disappear-lg');
    $two[0].offsetWidth = $two[0].offsetWidth;
    $two.addClass("appear-lg");

    $three.removeClass('appear-lg');
    $three[0].offsetWidth = $three[0].offsetWidth;
    $three.addClass("disappear-lg");
});
```

Notice the `offsetWidth` change in between changing the classes. This effectively has the effect of refreshing the animations.

http://jsfiddle.net/v6jcq6w8/1/

Comment: Ah yes, `offsetWidth`. IIRC this has the effect of forcing the browser to repaint… but it hardly seems like the "correct" solution to the problem. Thanks for mentioning this.

Comment: unfortunately, this seems to be the best solution at the moment! I also explored cloning and replacing the element as suggested [in this css-tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/)… long story short, I ran into issues with `clone()` destroying event bindings, so came back to good ol' `offsetWidth`. *sigh*